# Thermodynamics of air-conditioning

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm afraid this is a rather humdrum domestic question. We have a wall-mounted air-conditioner in our apartment at floor level. I made a small wooden table to sit over it. Basically four legs and a top with spaced wooden slats in a modernist style. The air blows mostly through the slats. My wife insists that the wood "absorbs" the cold and/or "blocks the flow" of air, so the air-conditioner must work harder. I suggested that this does not conform to my admittedly weak understanding of thermodynamics. Wood does not "absorb" cold without radiating it out anymore than the furniture does, and air flow is not "blocked" by spaced wooden slats about ten inches from the vent. These theories were rather scornfully rejected, along with the idea that I possessed even a grain of logic. Anyone care to take sides?

Comment: Include pictures! If the table creates air resistance, then it's true that the air conditioner has to work harder. Any form of resistance will set up a larger temperature gradient, meaning the rest of the room will be warmer than otherwise. Slats of any kind impose drag on airflow, but depends on the geometry. In terms of interpersonal advice your wife need not be so scornful towards you but you could consider acquiescing and placing the table elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was trying to think of it in terms of a kind of Carnot ideal heat engine. If you have a room of a certain size and the machine runs constantly cool air in, hot air out, would the temperature be changed by any objects placed in the "closed" room, including the table? I'd think it would be impacted only by things effectively sealing or blocking input/output, such as a cover on the vent or a wall halving the room size.

Comment: The Thermodynamics of heat pumps is very well known. Just search it.

Comment: Nothing "absorbs cold".  You can, however, block air flow.

Comment: Just take it to. the limit.  How effective would the air conditioning be if the slats enclosed the entire border?  So it's more of a "how much" situation than a "yes-no" situation.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander the problem with thinking of it as a Carnot engine is that a Carnot engine's efficiency depends only on the temperatures of the two reservoirs. So, indeed, something like wooden slats wouldn't affect the efficiency of such an engine. But departures from the ideal case are large and certainly depend on how easily air can flow.

Comment: On the topic of a heat engine. If the airflow around the air conditioner does not efficiently leave the air conditioner, it will be colder near the air conditioner. If T1 is the temperature outside, T2 is the temperature next to the air conditioner. You want T2 to be as large as possible, as close to T1 as possible, by letting the cold leave the area and letting the warm air of the room come to the air conditioner to be cooled.

Comment: Thanks, all. Makes sense and sort of as I suspected. In the "ideal" case, which never exists, objects in the room makes no difference, but circulation depends on all the complex physical realities. I suspect my little table makes almost zero difference, but I could not prove the case to my wife's satisfaction without instruments and measurements... and I do not intent to be THAT sort of obsessively self-vindicating person.